# Load data from an Excel file in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, vba

I have this problem. I have an app coded in vb.net and I have a FileUpload control where the user has to select an Excel file, and after the user clicks on a Button, I have to load the data from the Excel file to populate a GridView.

I have absolutely no idea of how I can do this. When I try to select the file that the user has selected, it doesn't open anything and an error shows

How can I open the file that the user has selected?

Edit: I don't know if the question was clear enough but what I want to know is how can I open a file that the user has selected at the FileUpload control

Comment: there's a lot of resources out there for this sort of job, try this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32437/Read-and-Write-Excel-Files

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions:
1. install excel and use interop to load the data. DO NOT DO THIS! It is SLOW, error prone and a nightmare and SLOW.
2. Use a liberary like EPPLUS (only modern files) or aspose.cells to read the data.